# Testing the Response code of a WebService without a running server

Tags: java, web-services, testing, junit

I would like to test my WebService with JUnit (EasyMock and Hamcrest) without having to start my server (Wildfly)

```
private RegisterUserWebService testeee = new RegisterUserWebService();

@Test
  public void test() {

    // Set Mocks for testee
    // ...
    //

    Response response = testee.registerUser();
    verifyAll();
    assertThat(response.getStatusInfo().getStatusCode(), equalTo(Status.CONFLICT));

  }
```

I am getting a ClassNotFoundException:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl
            at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:152)
            at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:120)
            at javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.newInstance(Response.java:848)
            at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Response.java:590)
            at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Response.java:601)
            at my.package.webservices.RegisterUserWebService.registerUser(RegisterUserWebService.java:50)
```

As I understand it, no implementation could be found for javax.ws.rs.core.Response, and the default one seems to be the glassfish one which I don't have, hence the ClassNotFoundException.

How could I tell my test to use the Response from Wildfly ?
Or is there another way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are a bit mistaken on what unit tests are: basically, unit tests are for testing the smallest "units" that exist (like classes, methods) at **build time**; so, in other words: without any connection to real file systems, servers, databases, etc. pp.

This means, you can use JUnit to test your classes that "prepare" input that is supposed to go somewhere; or you can test classes that process some "result" coming from somewhere. In both cases, you might use a mocking framework (like EasyMock or Mokito) to fake that external part that provides the input to your classes.

So, some pseudo code to show you what could be working:

```
RegisterUserWebService mockedService = ... create mock ...
Response mockedResponse = ... create mock ...
expect(mockedService.getStatusInfo() ...)
expect(mockedService.registerUser( params to match on )).andReturn(mockedResponse)

YourComponent underTest = new YourComponent ( mockedService )
underTest.doSomething()

verify ( that your mocks saw the calls you expected to happen )
```

Anything else would not be a unit test, but a function/integration test (because they need other components to be up and running)

So, you decision: you can do unit tests, but then your scope will be different; or you focus on writing functional tests here.

Comment: I mocked the Data the Webservice is supposed to deliver, I just wanted to test the HTTP Codes returned by my webservice (in different cases). I already have Unit Tests for the Service being called by the WebService, now I wanted to test the WebService itself. I don't understand the Exception...

Comment: The exception is pretty clear: the JUnit env is missing classes that this service needs; probably because your JUnit env is not setup to work as webserver. But what I am telling you is: if your **web service** requires a running web server; then there is not much point in **unit** testing that stuff.  For your web service class itself, well, you would have to write it in a way that anything it needs to **do** his job can be mocked when you really want to unit test it. Meaning: look up *dependency injection" and use that to insert "required externals" into your classes.

Comment: That I have done. I have provided mocks for everything the WebService needs (not with CDI but with setters). But then how do I unit test it, if I cannot test its Response ?

Comment: The point is: if you are able to create an object of your "service class"; and if all things that object is using were mocked ... then you would be able to call the methods of your service class and use asserts to check them. So it looks like you **assume** that mocked everything; but reality tells you: no, you didn't.

Comment: All right. I'll do integration tests instead. Thanks